# HTML mail drupal 8

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal and I am using Drupal 8.5.x. I have installed HTML mail module to send password recovery mail. I have copied the file to my theme directory and named it "htmlmail--user--password_reset.html.twig"

In this file, I have put some text but I don't think it is even being called.

and in MailSystem, I have following settings. (See image)

[image: MailSystem settings]

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Try fully clearing the caches and also including the base template in your theme (htmlmail.html.twig). I've run into occasions before where it needs the base template for it to look for/accept child templates.